# Prime number lazy sequence

Tags: f#

I am new in F# and I am just wondering if is there any way to get lazy sequence of prime numbers in F#.

In Haskell I use next code:

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = sieve[2..]
       where sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x | x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

In F# I can check if is the number is prime:

```
let isPrime (number : bigint) =
    match number with
        | _ -> seq { bigint(2) .. bigint(Math.Sqrt(float number))}
        |> Seq.exists (fun x -> if (number % x = bigint(0)) then true else false)
        |> not
```

But I don't know how to convert it to lazy sequence.

Comment: Do you need `bigint`? I doubt a sieve is going to be able to compute primes that won't fit in a `long` anytime soon.

Comment: Yes, I need because I am trying to solve the project eluer #3 task (http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=3).

Comment: small spoiler: the biggest prime factor in that number fits comfortably in a long int. You can also use the I-suffix to denote bigints: 0I instead of bigint 0.

Comment: Sidenote: there is no reason to check for `number % 4` and all the next even numbers - if `number % 2 == 0`, then the check wouldn't happen at all, and if it's not, then one can assume that `number % 4 != 0` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629734/the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-f) question for a lot of answers giving lazy prime number sequences in F#.

For a naive solution using your `isPrime` implementation (i.e. I'm thinking you may be interested in seeing how to go about generating a infinite sequence from a filter function in general), try this:

```
let primes =
    Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i + 2) //need to skip 0 and 1 for isPrime
    |> Seq.map (fun i -> bigint(i))
    |> Seq.filter isPrime
```

However, you'll probably want to go about solving Project Euler Problem 3 differently by implementing a function which specifically factorizes a number rather than exhaustively dividing the number by primes and taking the largest. Though you will eventually need a prime sequence generator for problems further on.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mimic Haskell's laziness, you can use the LazyList type found in FSharp.PowerPack.dll. The LazyList.Cons(p,xs) is a pattern match corresponding to p:xs in Haskell. The 'Delayed' in consDelayed is necessary, because the regular LazyList.cons will be too eager and take infinitely (limited by your patience of course) long.

You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325914/haskell-f-turners-sieve/2326121) question interesting. It's another Haskell prime sieve in F#.

Here's your code in F# (unfortunately rather ugly):

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll"

//A lazy stream of numbers, starting from x
let rec numsFrom x = LazyList.consDelayed x (fun () -> numsFrom (x+1I))

let rec sieve = function
    | LazyList.Cons(p,xs) ->
        LazyList.consDelayed p (fun () -> 
                xs |> LazyList.filter (fun x -> x%p <> 0I) |> sieve)
    | _ -> failwith "This can't happen with infinite lists"

let primes() = sieve (numsFrom 2I)
```

Example output in FSI:

```
> primes() |> Seq.take 14 |> Seq.toList;;
Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : System.Numerics.BigInteger list =
  [2I; 3I; 5I; 7I; 11I; 13I; 17I; 19I; 23I; 29I; 31I; 37I; 41I; 43I]
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution without F# powerpack

```
module Prime
    let isPrime n = 
        let bound = int (sqrt(float n))
        seq{2..bound}
        |> Seq.exists (fun x -> n % x = 0) 
        |> not
    let rec nextPrime n = 
        if isPrime (n + 1) then n + 1
        else nextPrime (n+1)
    let sequence = 
        Seq.unfold(fun n -> Some(n, nextPrime n)) 1
```