# Is this an optimal prime generator?

Tags: python, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

Is this in any way an optimal solution for finding primes? I am not trying to add every optimization under the sun, but is the principal good?

```
def primesUpto(self, x):
    primes = [2]
    sieve = [2]
    i = 3
    while i <= x:
        composite = False
        j = 0
        while j < len(sieve):
            sieve[j] = sieve[j] - 1
            if sieve[j] == 0:
                composite = True
                sieve[j] = primes[j]
            j += 1
        if not composite:
            primes.append(i)
            sieve.append(i*i-i)
        i += 1
    return primes
```

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, very interesting. Your code is actual honest to goodness ***genuine sieve of Eratosthenes*** IMHO, counting its way along the ascending natural numbers by decrementing each counter that it sets up for each prime encountered, by 1 on each step.

And it is very inefficient. [Tested on Ideone](http://ideone.com/EC3t4g) it runs at the same [empirical order of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) `~ n^2.2` (at the tested range of few thousand primes produced) as the famously inefficient [Turner's trial division sieve](http://ideone.com/cWYH4g) (in Haskell).

Why? Several reasons. ***First***, no **early bailout** in your test: when you detect it's a composite, you continue processing the array of counters, `sieve`. You have to, because of the ***second reason***: you **count** the difference **by decrementing** each counter by 1 on each step, with 0 representing your current position. This is the most faithful expression of the original sieve IMHO, and it is very inefficient: today our CPUs know how to add numbers in O(1) time (if those numbers belong to a certain range, 0 .. 2^32, or 0 .. 2^64, of course).

Moreover, our computers also have direct access memory now, and having calculated the far-off number we can mark it in a random access array. Which is the foundation of the efficiency of the sieve of Eratosthenes on modern computers - both the direct calculation, and the direct marking of multiples.

And ***third***, perhaps the most immediate reason for inefficiency, is the ***premature*** handling of the multiples: when you encounter 5 as a prime, you add its first multiple (not yet encountered) i.e. 25, *right away* into the array of counters, `sieve` (i.e. the distance between the current point and the multiple, `i*i-i`). That is much too soon. The addition of 25 must be ***postponed*** until ... well, until we encounter 25 among the ascending natural numbers. Starting to handle the multiples of each prime prematurely (at `p` instead of `p*p`) leads to having way too many counters to maintain - `O(n)` of them (where `n` is the number of primes produced), instead of just `O(π(sqrt(n log n))) = O(sqrt(n / log n))`.

The *postponement* optimization [when applied on a similar "counting" sieve in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11732578/849891) brought its empirical orders of growth from `~ n^2.3 .. 2.6` for `n = 1000 .. 6000` primes down to just above `~ n^1.5` (with obviously enormous gains in speed). When counting was further replaced by direct addition, the resulting measured empirical orders of growth were `~ n^1.2 .. 1.3` in producing up to hlaf a million primes (although in all probability it would gain on `~ n^1.5` for bigger ranges).

Comment: Thanks for the evaluation, it helps a lot.